# how to randomly distribute numbers among the elements of a vector? in R

Tags: r, random, vector

here's my problem.

suppose I have a vector:

```
vec <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
```

and I want to randomly distribute 6 values among the elements of my vector, in a way that sometimes an element gets something (between 1 and 6), sometimes gets nothing, but always the sum of the values must sum up to 6. So in one instance for example the values will get distributed like this:

```
3,0,1,0,2,0
```

in another like this:

```
1,0,1,1,2,1
```

and so forth.

Is there any easy way to do this in R?

thank you very much in advance.

Tina.

Comment: are you looking for sample with replacement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**

This is better, as it will almost certainly produce various partitions with the relative frequency that you're expecting:

```
as.vector(rmultinom(1, size=length(vec), prob=rep(1, length(vec))))
# [1] 4 0 1 0 1 0
```

---

The combinatorial object you're after here is called a ["partition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). The **partitions** package includes a number of nifty functions for generating different flavors of partition. With a little tweaking of the `parts()` function's output, we get just what you are looking for.

```
library(partitions)

## Create a function
randPartition <- function(vec) {
    pp <- parts(length(vec))
    sample(pp[,sample(ncol(pp), 1)])
}

## Try it out a few times
randPartition(vec)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
randPartition(vec)
# [1] 2 0 0 2 0 2
randPartition(vec)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 6
```

Comment: You may want to think a bit more, though, about whether this approach will generate the various partitions with the relative frequency that you want them...

Comment: I like @flodel's answer as well (that got lost with the deleted answer of Ricardo): `table(factor(sample(vec, 6, replace = TRUE), levels = vec))`